# Remove add to cart for variable products with no price in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently trying to build a woocommerce site with a some simple products but mostly variable products.

I've managed to add some php which will remove the price if the product is either priced at 0 or has no price at all, but I need to remove the "add to cart" button too.

When i try to add any further filters such as this one

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'remove_add_to_cart_option', 10, 2 );
function remove_add_to_cart_option( $purchasable, $product ) {

    if( $product-&gt;get_price() == 0 )
        $purchasable = false;
    return $purchasable;
}
```

it crashes the site (I'm using my custom functions to edit the function php). Here is the full code...

```
    // Variable and simple product displayed prices
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'empty_and_zero_price_html', 20, 2 );
function empty_and_zero_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    $empty_price = __(' ','woocommerce');

    if( $product->is_type('variable') )
    {
        $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );

        if ( empty( $prices['price'] ) ) {
            return $empty_price; // <=== HERE below for empty price
        } else {
            $min_price     = current( $prices['price'] );
            $max_price     = end( $prices['price'] );
            if ( $min_price === $max_price && 0 == $min_price ) {
                return $empty_price; // <=== HERE for zero price
            }
            elseif ( $min_price !== $max_price && 0 == $min_price ) {
                return wc_price( $max_price );
            }
        }
    }
    elseif( $product->is_type('simple') )
    {
        if ( '' === $product->get_price() || 0 == $product->get_price() ) {
            return $empty_price; // <=== HERE for empty and zero prices
        }
    }
    return $price;
}

// Product Variation displayed prices
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'empty_and_zero_variation_prices_html', 10, 3);
function empty_and_zero_variation_prices_html( $data, $product, $variation ) {

    if( '' === $variation->get_price() || 0 == $variation->get_price() )
        $data['price_html'] = __(' ','woocommerce'); // <=== HERE for empty and zero prices

    return $data;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'remove_add_to_cart_option', 10, 2 );
function remove_add_to_cart_option( $purchasable, $product ) {
    
    if( $product-&gt;get_price() == 0 )
        $purchasable = false;
    return $purchasable;
}
```

Comment: `$product-&gt;get_price()` most obviously needs to be `$product->get_price()`

Comment: That's caught the error but the filter itself isn't changing anything on the site

Comment: Well, you’ll have to do some debugging then. You’re the one sitting in front of the whole thing and with access to the relevant parts, not us.

Comment: I think it may be because it's a variable product and this filter only works on simple products

Comment: Which one are you talking about, `woocommerce_is_purchasable`? And what in particular makes you think that? Your results? Or did you find this documented/mentioned anywhere?

Comment: "public boolean #is_purchasable( ) returns false if the product cannot be bought "is listed in the method summary on the woocommerce docs. 

I presume that this is used when you set a simple product at 0 price it removes the price and add to basket function automatically without any additional code. 

What I'm trying to do is for that to happen when a variable product has some or all variations priced at 0 it hides the add to cart button and the price.